# How do I turn the mic off?

Tags: firefox-os

I'm using navigator.getUserMedia for a voice memo app. It works like a charm.

When I quit the app, the microphone stays on (there is a notification "Audio Memos Mic is on" and the red dot remains in the status bar. It stays on even after the phone went to sleep for fifteen minutes.

How do I turn the mic off when I quit the app. I've check the mediastream API but couldn't find any reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the stop method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder.stop

There may be a better way but I got the light to turn off on minimized apps by using code similar to:
mediaRecorder was a ref to the MediaRecorder object tied to the stream.  You can also just call stop on the stream returned by the GetUserMedia call.  Also had to call setup on init of app as well.

```
function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (document.hidden) {
     console.log("hidden");
     if( gumStream ){
         gumStream.stop();
         mediaRecorder = null;
     }
  } else  {
     console.log("visible");
     setup(); //Call getUserMedia
  }
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
```

Comment: Yes. That's how I stop the recording process. But the mic stays on. BTW its a Flame phone and FFOS1.3

Comment: Are you quitting the app or just minimizing it?  I tried it on my Flame 1.3 and the mic goes off a few seconds after I kill the app.  When I minimized it stays on.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I guess that brings up the real question. I've always assumed that tapping the home button means quitting the app. But I gather that's just minimizing it. So I have to hold the home button as if I wanted to switch apps and the tap the delete button?

Comment: I've played with is and realize that I need to revamp the app quite a bit. I've gotten the mic off with the stream.stop() command, but then I have to call getUserMedia again, otherwise the stream is gone. So, it's a nice challenge. Thanks again for your help.